# How to run PyTorch on GPU with CUDA 10.2 on Windows 7?

Tags: python, cuda, gpu, nvidia

I want to test run some finite-difference time domain (FDTD) simulations using parallelization on a GPU and compare the speed to CPU-based simulation runs. This is basically my very first attempt at using GPU acceleration for scientific computing.

My system configuration:

```
CPU: Intel Core i7-4930K @ 3.40 GHz
GPU: Gigabte GeForce GTX 1650 OC LP 4.0 GB
RAM: 32.0 GB (16.0 GB usable)
OS: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit
```

This GPU has [896 CUDA cores](https://www.gigabyte.com/de/Graphics-Card/GV-N1650OC-4GL/sp#sp) and [compute capability 7.5](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cuda-enabled-geforce-1650/81010), so I'm expecting a significant acceleration when compared to running my simulation on "only" 12 CPU cores.

The simulation script uses the [`fdtd`](https://github.com/flaport/fdtd) simulation package and I'm using Jupyter notebooks for convenience. If you're interested in some actual code reference, I can recommend taking a look at the short example scripts on the `fdtd` GitHub page.

I've installed the CUDA ToolKit version 10.2 as this appears to be the last version with Windows 7 support. Version 11.0+ appears to support Windows 10+ only, at least according to the [download page](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive) (can anyone confirm this?).

I've also installed `torch` + `torchvision` + `torchaudio`, simply because [PyTorch includes these packages](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) during installation procedure. However, I got stuck when trying to install the *Python* CUDA ToolKit as it [seems to require](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#pip-wheels-installation-linux) another package called `nvidia-pyindex`, [which is not available for Windows](https://github.com/NVIDIA/tensorflow/issues/12#issuecomment-754086215). Moreover, I'm confused by the PyTorch installation command for CUDA 10.2 which says *`"CUDA-10.2 PyTorch builds are no longer available for Windows, please use CUDA-11.6"`*, especially since they [clearly state](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#supported-windows-distributions):

> Supported Windows Distributions
>
> PyTorch is supported on the following Windows distributions:
>
> **Windows 7** and greater; Windows 10 or greater recommended.
> Windows Server 2008 r2 and greater

In the Python interpreter, I'm getting

```
Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
False
```

and trying to set the CUDA backend in the simulation package returns

```
import fdtd

fdtd.set_backend("torch.cuda.float64")

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 35>()
     31 display(HTML("<style>.container {width:100% !important;}</style>"))
     33 #fdtd.set_backend("numpy")
     34 #fdtd.set_backend("torch.float64")
---> 35 fdtd.set_backend("torch.cuda.float64")

File C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\fdtd\backend.py:376, in set_backend(name)
    374     raise RuntimeError("Torch backend is not available. Is PyTorch installed?")
    375 if name.startswith("torch.cuda") and not TORCH_CUDA_AVAILABLE:
--> 376     raise RuntimeError(
    377         "Torch cuda backend is not available.\n"
    378         "Do you have a GPU on your computer?\n"
    379         "Is PyTorch with cuda support installed?"
    380     )
    382 if name.count(".") == 0:
    383     dtype, device = "float64", "cpu"

RuntimeError: Torch cuda backend is not available.
Do you have a GPU on your computer?
Is PyTorch with cuda support installed?
```

How should I progress from here?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there seems to be fairly little you can do with your current software stack - Windows 7 is going to become an increasingly larger pain in the butt as software progresses, especially GPU drivers. The simplest way would be to upgrade that to Windows 10.

If you really, really don't want to or can't switch, you could also look into dual-booting a Linux system on the same machine. That should get you some more flexibility for the NVIDIA driver.

---

**edit**: There may be another way to sidestep this - it's downgrading Pytorch, like I said before in the comments. According to the interactive table at https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#start-locally, PyTorch LTS 1.8.2 does support Windows 7 with CUDA 10.2, if you run it through Python 3.8, which I see you do. You can try installing that particular version with (found from that table):

```bash
pip3 install torch==1.8.2 torchvision==0.9.2 torchaudio===0.8.2 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/lts/1.8/cu102
```

Once you get that installed, you should of course verify it's running via GPU using the `import torch; torch.cuda.is_available()` you used earlier.

`fdtd` doesn't have a particular minimal version dependency on PyTorch, which usually  means things might break - but there's a chance they won't.

Comment: I'm stuck with this machine for now. But why do you think that the errors are caused specifically by Windows 7? Is Windows 7 incompatible with CUDA?

Comment: Well, I'm mostly basing that on this part: `CUDA-10.2 PyTorch builds are no longer available for Windows, please use CUDA-11.6".`, as that's what your issue boils down to. PyTorch has effectively moved on from supporting Win 7, due to the abandonment of Cuda 10; `fdtd` is most likely being based on current PyTorch versions, so the same applies. You could in theory try to dig through older versions of PyTorch, and find an older version of `fdtd`, but that comes with abandoning all the bugfixes that have been introduced since `fdtd` worked with Cuda 10. That's... risky.

Comment: Are you certain? PyTorch makes a [very different statement](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#supported-windows-distributions): *"PyTorch is supported on the following Windows distributions: **Windows 7** and greater; Windows 10 or greater recommended. Windows Server 2008 r2 and greater"*

Comment: Okay, I wasn't precise there - Windows 7 in general might be supported, but the combo of CUDA 10.2 and Windows 7 isn't, as seen from their interactive table just above the linked part. I'm sympathetic to your plight, I know the pain of working with legacy hardware in academia with this kind of, er, boundary condition :( But I'm really afraid it's going to be hard to sidestep this. What I would suggest is to ask this question again, with another title - your problem is really "run Pytorch with GPU in a constrained CUDA 10.2, windows 7 environment", rather than strictly a coding one.

Comment: Actually, let me edit the answer a little, I have another idea but the comment field is too short ^^'

Comment: Take a look at the edit!

Comment: Bravo, you got it!! I should have checked the other options as well. `torch.cuda.is_available()` now evaluates to `True` - on to the next problem! Thx